# Clean the infos Facebook Log Out

Tags: android, facebook, logout

I want to clean my userinfo textview when I log out the Facebook. But I don't know which part I'm logging out actually. And don't know where I have to clean information(firstname, last name) Any idea? Thanks in advance.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView userinfo;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginButton loginButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    userinfo= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
   loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
        {

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Oturum başarı ile açıldı!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setFacebookData(loginResult);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Giriş işlemi iptal edildi.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Giriş başarısız.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });






}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void setFacebookData(final LoginResult loginResult)
{
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
        {
            try {


                String firstName = response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name");
                String lastName = response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name");
                Log.i("Login"+ "FirstName", firstName);
                Log.i("Login" + "LastName", lastName);
                userinfo.setText("Hoşgeldiniz, "+firstName + " " +lastName+"!");



            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using FB sdk button, then it will log user out on its click. else on click of you button just call

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

it will by default apply these commands

```
AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
Profile.setCurrentProfile(null);
```

& you can clear you textviews by setting "" (eg. textview.setText("");)

Comment: Can I settext in end of the registercallback function?

Answer (score 0):

As you are not storing either firstname or lastname in sharedPref or database there is no need to clear any data just set the textview :

```
userinfo.setText("");
```

Comment: Should I do that in onCreate()?